# Show that for any integer $x, ax\not\equiv1\pmod{a\cdot b}$ where $a,b$ are integers that $1<a$ and $1<b$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

> If $m$ is a natural number greater than $1$ and is not prime, then we know that $m=ab$, where $1<a<m$ and $1<b<m$. Show that there is no integer $x$ such that $ax≡1\pmod{m}$.

**My thoughts:**

What I think is $ax$ can only congruent to multiple of $a$ under mod $a\cdot b$ and since $a>1$ that means it could never congruent to $1$.

\begin{align}
ax&\equiv y\pmod{a\cdot b}\tag*{Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, solve $y$}\\
y&=a(b\cdot k+x)\tag*{Case1: $ax<ab;k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
y&=a(x-b+b\cdot k)\tag*{Case2: $ax\ge ab;k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
y&\neq 1\tag*{Since $a>1$}\\
\end{align}

Is this idea correct, are there other approaches to prove this statement ?

Comment: There's no need for two cases. Instead we have $$ \exists\, x\!:\ a\,x\equiv c\!\!\!\pmod{\!ab}\,\Rightarrow\, \exists\, x,y\!:\ \color{#c00}a\,x+\color{#c00}ab\,y = c\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}a\mid c,\ \ {\rm so}\ \ |c|\ge |a| > 1\,\Rightarrow\, c\neq 1$$

Comment: @BillDubuque thx, indeed a better approache, I should notice $a\mid c$ implies $|c|\ge |a|$

Comment: I'd rewrite your proof as follows: if $\,y\equiv ax\pmod{\!ab}\,$ then, by definition of congruence, there is an integer $k$ with $\, y = ax+kab = a(x+kb)\ $ so $\ a\mid y,\,$ so $\ |y|>|a|\ge 1\  \ $

Comment: i.e. any common factor $\,a\,$  a residue $r$ has with a modulus $n$ *persists* as a factor in every  $\ r' \equiv r\pmod{\!n}\ $ Such a nontrivial factor exists $\iff r\,$ is not invertible $\bmod n,\,$ which is independent of the residue rep chosen.